# is cluster for node.js required when running it as a job worker?

Tags: node.js

Do we need cluster module for a node.js script which just fetches some job from gearman server or from a rest api like in AWS SQS and performs it?
What i know is that, cluster is more useful in case of socket sharing (ex listening on a port) like in a web server.
PS: I am already using monit to monitor and restart these daemon process in case of a crash and in future planning to use pm2 (in non cluster mode, i.e. without -i flag).

Comment: Depends on what _"some job"_ is.

Comment: @robertklep, consider "_some job_" as sending a push notification by calling GCM/APN's API or in general it can be any thing. In what case it will matter?

Comment: If the jobs are CPU-intensive, you should probably consider using `cluster`. But if the jobs are mostly I/O-bound (like GCM/APN handling), you can get pretty good performance with just one process.

Comment: @robertklep, can you please put some more light on this "_If the jobs are CPU-intensive, you should probably consider using cluster_"? Some online resources will be great. Also, as i know, we should never do any CPU bound things in node at all and even if we need it, we should go for fibers etc.

Comment: If you search around on SO you will most likely find some useful info on Node.js and CPU-intensive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to use the cluster module in order to service multiple operations from some sort of work queue.  You should use the cluster module when it's specific features match up well with the type of work you are doing (load balancing multiple incoming connections).

In fact, if the operations to be done are mostly asynchronous things (such as sending an update to an external database), you may not even need multiple processes.  But, if you do need multiple processes, then you can use the various options in the `process` module to start other work processes to carry out individual tasks and use the main central server to monitor and coordinate these other processes.  This is part of what the cluster module does, but it's use is more specialized than just something that starts other external processes that you could code yourself.